# How to query mongoDB using Mongoengine with several "WHERE" arguments (what is AND)?

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine

I'm currently querying a MongoDB with the following mongoengine query:

```
queryResults = Event.objects(title__icontains=q)
```

This works well, but I want to add another argument so it becomes something like this:

```
queryResults = Event.objects(title__icontains=q and end__gte=datetime.utcnow())
```

Unfortunately, simply using `and` doesn't work here. I tried other things like `&` and `&&`, but to no avail. I also checked [the mongoengine docs](http://docs.mongoengine.org/guide/querying.html), but I can't find anything about it.

Would anybody have any idea how I could do this? All tips are welcome!

Comment: Maybe a "," between them? like (title__icontains=q,end__gte=datetime.utcnow())

Comment: @VincentBeltman - Of course! It's obviously simple kwargs. How stupid of me! Thaks a million! (ps. If you add it as an answer, I can accept it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting a "," between this:

```
queryResults = Event.objects(title__icontains=q, end__gte=datetime.utcnow())
```